# Query for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working out with a data in R.

```
a<-rep(NA,400)
for(i in 1:10){for(j in 0:40){print(dat$V2[i]-j)}}
```

Instead of printing, I want to add that value into an empty array (a). I would be thankful if someone help me with the same.

Comment: Please explain what is dat, V2 etc in your code, write more what operation you want to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way only using loops:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  for(j in 0:39){
    print(i*40 - 39 + j)
    a[i*40 - 39 + j] = dat$V2[i]-j}}
```

PS: as you want to create a vector with 400 observations, and `i` goes from 1 to 10, `j` needs to have "length" 40, so you want it to be 0:39.

When you want to create a vector (1 dimentional) with a doble loop, the following formula normally applies:

```
index of the vector = i*length(j) - (length(j)-1) + j
```

Answer (score 3):

In a case like this (nested loops), often the easiest way is to add a counter to keep track of positions in the array:

```
a <- rep(NA, 400)
counter <- 1
for(i in 1:10){
  for(j in 0:40){
    a[counter] <- dat$V2[i]-j
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```r
#a<-rep(NA,400)
#for(i in 1:10){for(j in 0:40){print(dat$V2[i]-j)}}

a <- as.numeric( sapply( 1:10, function(i){
    sapply( 0:40, function(j) {
        dat$V2[i]-j
    })
}))
```

`sapply` is useful here because countrary to a for loop it returns something with each loop. So in this case I first loop over 1:10, like your for loop, with the useful difference that it actually returns something each time.

What it does in each iteration is to run a new nested block, also using `sapply`, this time looping over 0:40, also this time returning something, this time its the expression you have innermost in your for loop.

So for 10 times, for each of 1:10, it will loop over 0:40, each time calculating your expression and returning it, which should result in it getting calculated and returned as you want.

`as.numeric` is wrapped around it to make sure it stays as one long vector, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: can you please ellaborate, like what is function, etc.

Comment: The difference from a nested for each loop is that you don't have to worry about preparint the vector beforehand and then calculating which index this element should go into. They are just all automatically aligned and stuffed into your vector.

Comment: `function` is a keyword to define a.. function in R. You have likely done this before. It creates a block of code that can later be run when you like. It is besides the scope of your question, but is among the really early things you learn when you learn R.